# QGIS : How to add points from GPS stream data

Tags: qgis, gps, leica-geo-office

I try to place points on QGIS using the GPS plugin but it does not like me.

GPS stream is good, I have the read on the data on port com 66,

QGIS seems to be good with it since it locates correctly where I am, finds latitude, longitude and elevation, satellites and so on:

[image]

but saving a point using the add entity on a point vector layer in edit mode returns NULL geometry.

I tried on a shape and spatialite layers.

Should I define a special coordinate system for my layers?

Adding a point manually works fine.

Comment: this gps plugin saves to shapefile but looks like you need to set it up before live tracking http://www.mappinggeek.ca/QGISPythonPlugins/trackgps/TheQGISGPSTrackerPlugin.html#Setting_Options

Comment: Ty for the link, I was stuck on qgis page which is far less complete. A part of it should at least be set here http://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/live_GPS_tracking.html